# Is Embedded active MQ broker compatible with Spring Boot version 3.2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, jms-queue

how to start Embedded active MQ broker in Spring boot 3.2.0 ?

I have JMS listener, want to test that Message is publishing and my Listener is Listening or not?

```
How to write test case of JMS Listener in spring boot version 3.2.0 with gradle?
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You should consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).